# Is there a way to access Vue object global properties not set via .prototype?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm attempting to add some global constants via a Typescript plugin that looks something like this:

```
import _Vue from "vue";

export function Constants(Vue: typeof _Vue, options?: any): void {
  Vue.foobar = "global foobar";
  Vue.prototype.$foobar = "prototype foobar";
}
```

In a template the first reference below works, but the second does not. The plugin is Used in the main.ts file (code not included here) What am I doing wrong? I've found examples of the global property declaration in several blog posts, but no examples of actual usage.

```
<template>
  <div>
    Works: {{ $foobar }}
    Error: {{ foobar }}
  </div>
</template>
```

The second case produces this Vue warn:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "foobar" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Comment: What you want to use to add new `data` properties are [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin).

Answer (score 0):

Try include ts-loader into vue rules inside webpack.config.js:

`ts: [{loader: 'ts-loader', options: {appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] }}]`